# Killit - Bookmarklet to replace single images from the page

Tags: script, chat, images, bookmarklet

### About

Bookmarklet that replaces any selected image on the page with:

[image: "troll face"]

#### How to use.

You first need to "install" the bookmarklet by visiting the [**project homepage**](http://rlemon.github.com/Killit/) and dragging the button to your bookmarks bar.
After the button is there, simply press it, then select an image on the page.
Clicking on anything that is not an image will cancel the operation.

#### License

Killit is released under the [WTFPL](http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/).

#### Download

You can download the code or just *Fork* it here:
https://github.com/rlemon/Killit

### Contact

I can be reached at `rob.lemon@gmail.com`.

#### NOTE:

this was designed to be used in the Chat system, however it has many other uses. Some sites do funny things to their images to make them not look like images... I cannot help this situation. Sorry.

Comment: I think you should really put an unminified version on github...

Comment: Will do boss man.